# javascript - download zip which contains csv files inside

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I receive a zip file in response to a ajax GET request. This zip file contains csv files inside it.I am able to download the zip file properly but the csv file inside it is missing and shows error as "Unexpected end of archive."

Comment: Have you checked the source ZIP is not corrupt? Is the file size of the downloaded ZIP file the same as the source? Sounds like you have a corrupt ZIP file.

Comment: Try to open the zip file manually (in your file explorer) and see if it actually contains the CSV file

Comment: TheEdge - Yes the zip is corrupted. The zip that download is of smaller size as compared to the original file.